# Figure with subplots using different plotting types

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes, subplot, figure

How can I plot a figure with several subplots, using different plotting types (line, scatter etc.)?
When trying to use plt.scatter or plot.scatter or other, I get the error:

> 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'

How can I initiate the attribute here?

When using the "normal" plot axes[2].plot(kind='scatter') as an attribute, I get the error:

> Unknown property kind

When just using uniformly the axes.plot(x,y,....) for each of the three subplots they are displayed well as lineplots

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(21,4))
fig =  plt.figure()


axes[0].plot(dur_d,inter_d,color='purple', lw=0.5, alpha=0.5, linestyle='dashed',marker='+',markersize=10,markeredgecolor='red',markeredgewidth=3) # RGB Hex Code
axes[0].set_xlabel('Duration')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Interest')
axes[0].set_title('Interest on different loan durations')

axes[1].plot(amount_a,inter_a,color='purple', lw=0.5, alpha=1, linestyle='dashed',marker='+',markersize=1,markeredgecolor='red',markeredgewidth=1) # RGB Hex Code
axes[1].set_xlabel('Loan amount')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Interest')
axes[1].set_title('Interest on different loan amounts')

axes[2].plt.scatter(ltv_l,inter_l,alpha=0.5, color='purple') # RGB Hex Code
axes[2].set_xlabel('LTV')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Interest')
axes[2].set_title('Interest on different LTV')
```

Comment: You should not call `fig =  plt.figure()` as it erase the figure and axes created by `fig,axes = plt.subplots(...)`. Also note that there is a difference in calling conventions between standard matplotlib (`ax.scatter(....)`) and pandas (`my_dataframe.plot(kind=..., ax=axes[0]`). Pandas plotting uses matplotlib internally, but has a different way to call its functions, centered on dataframes. It really is confusing when you are confronted with them the first time. Moreover, matplotlib functions are often used to fine-tune pandas plots.

Comment: In short, leaving out `fig =  plt.figure()` and replacing `axes[2].plt.scatter(...)` by `axes[2].scatter(...)` should probably get things to work (depending on what's inside the variables).

Comment: @JohanC yeah, actually it worked out. I imagined it much more difficult! Thx a lot.